# swipeActions in a list: button can not be pressed

Tags: list, button, swiftui, swipe-gesture

I'm trying to add a simple swipe action to my list. But for some reason the button can not be pressed. When I perform a full swipe it works though.

This is my code:

```
var listView: some View {
    List {
        ForEach(Array(debits.enumerated()), id: \.element) { index, debit in
            HStack {
                Text(debit.name)
                    .swipeActions(allowsFullSwipe: true) {
                        Button(action: {
                            print("Hi \(index)")
                        }, label: {
                            Image(systemName: "slider.horizontal.3")
                        })
                    }
                Spacer()
                Text(String(debit.value))
                    .frame(width: 70, alignment: .trailing)
                Text("€")
                Divider().padding(.leading, 5)
                Toggle("", isOn: $debits[index].toggle)
                    .onChange(of: debit.toggle) { newValue in
                        calculateAvailable()
                    }
                    .frame(width: 50)
            }
        }
    }.listStyle(.plain).lineLimit(1)
}
```

Like I said, a press on the button does not print anything but the full swipe does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the answer. I used this code to dismiss the keyboard when tapping somewhere. This prevented the button from being pressed.

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        my code
    }
    .onTapGesture {
        UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the `.swipeActions` modifier to the `HStack` containing the whole row:

```
List {
    ForEach(Array(debits.enumerated()), id: \.element) { index, debit in
        HStack {
            Text(debit.name)
                
            Spacer()
            Text(String(debit.value))
                .frame(width: 70, alignment: .trailing)
            Text("€")
            Divider().padding(.leading, 5)
            Toggle("", isOn: $debits[index].toggle)
                .onChange(of: debit.toggle) { newValue in
                    calculateAvailable()
                }
                .frame(width: 50)
        }
        .swipeActions(allowsFullSwipe: true) {
            Button(action: {
                print("Hi \(index)")
            }, label: {
                Image(systemName: "slider.horizontal.3")
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Also, I would recommend adding a stable `id` to your `Debit` structure.  Something like this:

```
struct Debit: Hashable, Identifiable {
    var name: String
    var value: Double
    var toggle: Bool
    let id = UUID()
}
```

and use that as your id:

```
ForEach(Array(debits.enumerated()), id: \.element.id) { index, debit in
```

If you weren’t enumerating to get the index, then you’d simply be able to iterate over `debits` since the items are `Identifiable`:

```
ForEach($debits) { $debit in
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. Unfortunately moving the .swipeActions did not help. The full swipe gesture still works but a press on the button does not print anything.

Comment: Did you try adding the stable `id`? SwiftUI needs this to function properly especially if you are deleting items.

Comment: Yes, I did. It didn't help in my case.

Answer (score 0):

This is working fine, the HStack is your problem. Try to set the swipaction on the HStack

```
List {
    ForEach(YourList, id: \.self) { debit in

            
            Text(debit)
                .swipeActions(allowsFullSwipe: true) {
                    Button(action: {
                        print("Hi \(index)")
                    }, label: {
                        Text("test")
                    })
                }
        }
  }
enter code here
```

Comment: I tried to move the swipe action. Unfortunately the button press is still not working.

Comment: For testing remove the hstack, see my answer. This is working.

Answer (score 0):

Also using @FocusState to close keyboard don't let you to press swipe action buttons..
You should not use onTapGesture on whole View

```
@FocusState private var fieldIsFocused: Bool
        .onTapGesture {
            fieldIsFocused = false
        }
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35506366)

Comment: In swiftUI, if you ad FocusState on view that cause exact same issue LksMrx said

Answer (score -1):

I also had this exact same problem and it turns out a containing view had an .onTapGesture handler which was capturing the presses on the button effectively making it only work after the full swipe, but not when tapped.

Comment: This essentially repeats the accepted answer.